# Axios not setting data

Tags: vue.js, axios

I'm trying to set data from an axios response but it seems to me like "this" is only in the scope of the axios function. I have tried different variations of the same code that I've seen on other posts, but none are working.

```
data: () => ({
      storeKey: 'dayspanState',
      calendar: Calendar.months(),
      readOnly: false,
      defaultEvents: [],
      ticket_event: [],
}),

created(){
    this.get_tickets();
    console.log(this.ticket_event);
},

methods:
{
  get_tickets(){
     axios.get('/api/get_patching_tickets')
        .then(function (response) {
           this.ticket_event = response.data;
           }.bind(this));
  },
}
```

Second trial

```
created(){
        var self = this;
        axios.get('/api/get_patching_tickets')
        .then(function (response) {
           self.ticket_event = response.data;
           });
        console.log(this.ticket_event);            
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have postman installed? Can you query the URL you are trying to call and see what the result is? the one which you pass to your axios call `axios.get('/api/get_patching_tickets'`...

Comment: yes, my route works, i even use the same axios functions in other components and it works too. that's why im confused. When i console.log(response.data) I get my routed data. i think its a variable scope issue

Comment: Can you try assigning a an array object value to your `ticket_event` variable. Then  prior to getting the result on the `axios.get` call, do a console log and see the value. Then in your response, perform another console.log of the `response.data` object and see the values. Kindly post the console window with your question.

Comment: So you're telling that the Second trial doesn't work either? Have you checked your data with the Vue dev tool for Chrome/Firefox browser? And what does a `console.log(response)` return in the `.then`?

Comment: Use an arrow function instead of `function(response)`

Comment: You can use async await but you are using vue so there is no problem if you are using `ticket_event` inside render coz vue will automatically update your view when data is updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try rewriting your function like:

```
created(){
    axios.get('/api/get_patching_tickets')
    .then((response) => {
        this.ticket_event = response.data;
    }).finally(() => {
        console.log(this.ticket_event);
    });

    /* WARNING: the following console will not work as expected
    as the local value is set after the successful call
    while this is fired immediately after created is called
    */

    console.log(this.ticket_event);            
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The callbacks you passed to `.then` in `axios.get` are fine. I see the only problem with your code is that **it logs `this.ticket_event` right after calling `this.get_tickets()` - an asynchronous operation**, so it'll not log the updated value after the api call finish because `this.get_tickets()` operates asynchronously:

```
this.get_tickets(); // is an async operation
console.log(this.ticket_event); // will not get the most updated value of this.ticket_event
```

Try this to see if it works:

```
data() {
  return {
      storeKey: 'dayspanState',
      calendar: Calendar.months(),
      readOnly: false,
      defaultEvents: [],
      ticket_event: [],
  }
},

methods: {
  get_tickets() {
     return axios.get('/api/get_patching_tickets')
        .then(response => {
           this.ticket_event = response.data;
        });
  }
},

created() {
    this.get_tickets().finally(() => {
        console.log(this.ticket_event);
    });
}
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation it is appreciated, but I got an Error in created hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'finally' of undefined"

Comment: @ZoneMeOut glad you found out your answer. About the error I have absolutely no idea how can it be undefined, I'm not sure if you copied exactly my code or just some part, but `get_tickets` returned an axios get, it should be a `Promise`, how could be `undefined`. If you use the version `get_tickets` of yours on the question, without a `return` like mine, it might be `undefined`.